# Negative integer function

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, solidity-0.5.x, uint256

I have the following problem, one of my function has a variable where the `uint` **can** be negative but I don't know of that before the user enter in the form the integer. How do I settle this problem ?

Here is the smart-contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity  >=0.5.16;

contract SupChain{
    //List of events
    event orderCreated(uint _orderID, address _counterparty);
    event orderShipped(uint _orderID, address _counterparty);
    event orderStored(uint _orderID, address _counterparty);
    event orderOutOfCompliance(uint _orderID, address _counterparty);
    event orderCompleted(uint _orderID, address _counterparty);
    
    
    
    // List of variable
    
    
    // Possible state of the order
    enum StateType {Created, InTransit, Stored, OutOfComplicance, Completed}

    // An order of the supply chain
    struct Order{
        // ID of the order
        uint orderID;
        //Number of time the order has been shipped/stored 
        uint correspondingUpdate;
        // State of the order
        StateType state;
        // Barcode of the corder
        string barcode;
        // User starting the supply chain by introducing an order
        address initiatingCounterparty;
         // List  the products inside the order
        string productsList;
        // Temperature minimal of the recommended environment
        uint temperatureMinimal;
        // Temperature maximal of the recommended environment
        uint temperatureMaximal;
        // Expiration date of the products
        uint expirationDate;
        // Last destination of the order
        string finalDestination;
        // Date of creation/Shipping/Storage of the order
        uint date;
    }

    // Number of created order
    uint public orderCount = 0;

    mapping (uint => Order) public orders;

    function createOrder(string memory _barCode, string memory _productList, uint _min, uint _max, uint _expDate, string memory _fDestination) public{
        orderCount ++;
        orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, 1, StateType.Created, _barCode, msg.sender, _productList, _min, _max, _expDate, _fDestination, block.timestamp);
        emit orderCreated(orderCount, msg.sender);
    }
```

I thank in advance anybody who will take the time to help me.

Comment: why are you using a uint (rather than an int) if your integer will be signed?

Comment: @TC8 Because I didn't know... when I learned solidity trough tutorials everyone was using `uint` , so I tought it was the equivant to int from other languages... 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hmmmmm... change the `uint` to `int` perhaps?

Comment: @goodvibration Already done thanks to TC8 advice :). But thanks too for the help :D.